# MVVM Swapping out controls

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation

I'm new to C# and am trying to learn MVVM by building a simple Crud app. In my App I want to have a series of buttons that when the user clicks on it will load that user control. So when you click on the "Add Item" it will replace the existing control with the AddItemView. I was wondering how I go about this? A lot of the mvvm tutorials that I've seen so far they just have a single control on the MainMindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of task, you typically use a [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx). Bind the `Content` property of the control to a property of your ViewModel (`CurrentViewModel` for instance), and define `DataTemplates` in the resources for each type of ViewModel that can be displayed in the `ContentControl`. When you assign a ViewModel to `CurrentViewModel`, the `ContentControl` will pick the appropriate `DataTemplate` for the content.

**Main ViewModel**

```
private object _currentViewModel;
public object CurrentViewModel
{
    get { return _currentViewModel; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _currentViewModel)
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AddItemViewModel}">
        <v:AddItemView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FooViewModel}">
        <v:FooView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BarViewModel}">
        <v:BarView />
    </DataTemplate>
    ...
</Application.Resources>
```

**Main view**

```
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
...
```

In your case, in the command for the "Add item" button, you assign an instance of `AddItemViewModel` to `CurrentViewModel`

Comment: Let's say if I have instead of just a simple data object I have a group of items and some features. Could I Switch out UserControls instead of ViewModels, and each UserControl could even have it's own ViewModel and so on?